# A proof given $t=t_0$ minimal point for $f(t)=|\vec{u} + t\vec{v}|$

Tags: vectors

Given $\vec{u},\vec{v}$ and $f(t)=|\vec{u} + t\vec{v}|$
How can I use the fact that f(t) is minimal for $t=t_0$ to prove that
$|t_0\vec{v}|^2 + |\vec{u} + t_0\vec{v}|^2= |\vec{u}|^2$?

PS: looking for a hint
Thanks

Comment: Hint: $f(t)$ is minimal exactly when $f(t)^{2}$ is minimal. Expand $f(t)^{2}$ and minimize the quadratic.

Comment: I was on the right path but completely overlooked minimizing the quadratic. Thanks!